# How to limit the number of sessions for a specific login

Tags: sql-server, connections

How can we let just one program to connect to the database, in case many programs have the connection string.
(limit the number of sessions for a specific login)

Comment: Do you want to limit each program's access to only a single database or do you want to limit a single instance of a program to connect? Please elaborate your question a bit

Comment: Do you mean the other applications already connect but there is only one database on the server? How about disabling the login and creating a new one that's only being used by the correct program?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/193061/edit) to make it as clear as possible. The answers that were posted apparently all misunderstood your question. Make sure the question is clear and that you are asking about something like that. I still don't see what you want. Do you want "something like application roles" without using them? Or have you tried application roles and got stuck? Why can't you use application roles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all programs are using the same credentials in the connection string, you *might* be able to achieve what you're after by using a [Logon Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers) to limit the number of **sessions** for a specific login. For example, in the following code (*taken from the documentation*), the logon trigger denies log in attempts to SQL Server initiated by login login_test if there are already three user sessions created by that login.

```
USE master;  
GO  
CREATE LOGIN login_test WITH PASSWORD = '3KHJ6dhx(0xVYsdf' MUST_CHANGE,  
    CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON;  
GO  
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO login_test;  
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger  
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'login_test'  
FOR LOGON  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'login_test' AND  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND  
                original_login_name = 'login_test') > 3  
    ROLLBACK;  
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the connections by using a specific login for that application. Any other app with a different user will just not have rights to even connect to the server.

Answer (score -3):

Just have one logon per database.  Don't share it with other programs.